# Swap implementation that works with arbitrary slice

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement a wrapper around `container/heap` to make heap initialization simpler.

An important required function for the `heap.Interface` is `Swap (i, j int)`, which I implemented with `reflect.Swapper`. But it turns out this won't work, because the slice used for a heap may grow and the `swapper` I stored before initialization would be obsolete.

I solve this problem by overriding the `swapper` every time a new item get pushed into the heap. My complete implementation is pasted below:

```
package heaptools

import (
    "container/heap"
    "reflect"
)

var _ heap.Interface = &sliceHeap{}

type sliceHeap struct {
    slice   reflect.Value
    less    func(i, j int) bool
    swapper func(i, j int)
}

func (h *sliceHeap) Len() int {
    return h.slice.Elem().Len()
}

func (h *sliceHeap) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return h.less(i, j)
}

func (h *sliceHeap) Swap(i, j int) {
    if i == j {
        return
    }
    h.swapper(i, j)
}

func (h *sliceHeap) Push(x interface{}) {
    e := h.slice.Elem()
    e.Set(reflect.Append(e, reflect.ValueOf(x)))
    h.swapper = reflect.Swapper(e.Interface())
}

func (h *sliceHeap) Pop() interface{} {
    e := h.slice.Elem()
    last := e.Index(e.Len() - 1)
    e.SetLen(e.Len() - 1)
    return last.Interface()
}

func NewSliceHeap(slice interface{}, less func(i, j int) bool) heap.Interface {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(slice)
    sh := &sliceHeap{
        slice:   v,
        less:    less,
        swapper: reflect.Swapper(v.Elem().Interface()),
    }
    heap.Init(sh)
    return sh
}
```

But this solution makes pushing much slower. I've Googled and found the following way for general slice swapping:

```
A := []int{1,2}
V := reflect.ValueOf(A)
x, y := V.Index(0).Interface(), V.Index(1).Interface()
V.Index(0).Set(reflect.ValueOf(y))
V.Index(1).Set(reflect.ValueOf(x))
```

But it turns out to be even slower.

How can I make a faster `swapper` that works here?

Comment: Rather than creating a new `Swapper` every time you push an item, you could just set `h.swapper` to `nil`, and then when `Swap` is called, if your `Swapper` is `nil`, *then* create a new one. That way successive inserts don't cause unnecessary creations of new `Swappers` that won't be used. You're unlikely to write your own reflection-based swapper that's faster than the one in the stdlib but still correct - but if you do, you should submit a PR to have the stdlib updated with your implementation.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, it's unlikely to beat the builtin swapper without copying most of the reflect package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Adrian pointed out, it's hard to come up with a swap implementation that always points to the correct slice and is as fast as the ones returned by `reflect.Swapper`. Because `reflect.Swapper` chooses the fastest implementation possible based on some information only available in some private field in the package.

An obvious opportunity for optimization is to avoid unnecessary creation of new `Swapper`s.

As suggested by @Adrian, I can just set `h.swapper` to `nil` and only create a new one when `Swap` is indeed called.

We can make it even faster by checking if the address of the underlying array changes. Remember, new array is only allocated when there's no sufficient space in the slice, most of the time the address of the underlying array should be the same, and we don't need to create a new swap function.

With the two optimization above, the code would become:

```
func (h *sliceHeap) Swap(i, j int) {
    if i == j {
        return
    }
    if h.swapper == nil {
        h.swapper = reflect.Swapper(h.slice.Elem().Interface())
    }
    h.swapper(i, j)
}

func (h *sliceHeap) Push(x interface{}) {
    e := h.slice.Elem()
    slicePtr := e.Pointer()
    e.Set(reflect.Append(e, reflect.ValueOf(x)))
    // If the pointer to the first element of the slice changes, we need a new Swapper
    if e.Pointer() != slicePtr {
        h.swapper = nil
    }
}
```